# NullPointerException on Heroku but in Glassfish everythin is ok?

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, glassfish, entitymanager

I'm developing a simple application on JAVA EE using JSF, JPA and Maven.
the question is: Why the tomcat servlet on Heroku is returning null on the time to inject a ManagedBean while in Glassfish server everything is fine?

There are my codes:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "homeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class HomeBean {

//simple properties

@ManagedProperty(value="#{emFactoryBean}")
private EntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){     
    sitioService = new SitioService(factoryBean);
    sitios = sitioService.getSitios();
}

//Getters and setters
}
```

The exception occurs when a new instace of SitioService is created, In other words. Here is the factorBean Class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerFactoryBean {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public EntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.
            createEntityManagerFactory("prueba");
}

//getter and setter
}
```

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="prueba" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.sertracen.sivt.modelo.Imagen</class>
    <class>com.sertracen.sivt.modelo.Review</class>
    <class>com.sertracen.sivt.modelo.Sitio</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="{url}"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="{usuario}"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="{contraseña}"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Obviously my parameter connections are ok.

Hope for your answers!
Cheers!

----STACK TRACE:

```
om.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean homeBean
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sertracen.sivt.negocio.SitioService.<init>(SitioService.java:26)
at com.sertracen.sivt.web.HomeBean.init(HomeBean.java:75)
```

Comment: Post your SitioService please.

Comment: Probably because Tomcat is not a Java EE container. If you require features of Java EE, I recommend using [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io) on Heroku.